# How to move outside pie chart labels on angular apexcharts.js

Tags: angularjs, apexcharts

I'm trying to move the labels out of the pie chart, but I can't move them in any way, is there any way i angular to move them out of the pie chart? (Angular v14)
I don't quite understand the documentation so it would be great if someone could help me understand how to do this.

Typescript code:

```
  @ViewChild('chart') chart!: ChartComponent;
  public chartOptions: Partial<ChartOptions>;


  constructor() {
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [45, 50, 22],
      chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        width: '270px',
      },
      labels: ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C'],
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            chart: {
              width: 100,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        horizontalAlign: 'center',
      },
      dataLabels: {
        offSetY: 50,
        // add this part to remove %
        enabled: true,
        
      },
    };
  }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="chartContainer" style="width: 30%;">
  <apx-chart 
    [series]="chartOptions.series" 
    [chart]="chartOptions.chart" 
    [labels]="chartOptions.labels" 
    [responsive]="chartOptions.responsive" 
    [legend]="chartOptions.legend"
    [dataLabels]="chartOptions.dataLabels">
</apx-chart>
</div>
```

I tried to put "offset", "offsetY", etc, inside the datalabel, but they didn't move an inch

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak [`dataLabels`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/datalabels/) and [`plotOptions.pie.dataLabels`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/pie/#dataLabels) in your `chartOptions`. I give you a basic example (without Angular for practical reasons...):

```js
let options = {
  series: [45, 50, 22],
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    height: 350
  },
  labels: ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C'],
  dataLabels: {
    style: {
      colors: ['black']
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        offset: 60
      }
    }
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I need to do it in angular and this way it doesn't work for me...

Comment: What did you do exactly? Could you share updated code?

Comment: It is the code that I have uploaded in the question. It won't let me in dataLabels move out the label.